# Can't step into wcf function with C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm still a bit new to WCF.  I followed a tutorial on Pluralsight.  In my solution, I have:

WCF project "MyCodeLibrary"
Console app "ConsoleHost"
 --host for the service, 
MVC project.

The mvc project references the wcf project.  In my mvc project, I have mylibservice.svc that contains:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyCodeLibrary.MyLIbService"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

There is no code behind on this file.  If I start the consolehost app, everything works fine, but I can't step into the wcf code. I have a breakpoint in my contoller on the line that calls the service function, but I get

"Unable to automatically debug "MyCodeLibrary".  The remote procedure could not be debugged.  This usually indicates that debuggin has not been enabled on the server."

I have  on the service and the mvc project.

My code to call the function is:

```
WebChannelFactory<IMyLibService> cf =
    new WebChannelFactory<IMyLibService>(
        new Uri("http://localhost:8084/mylib"));
IMyLibService client = null;
client = cf.CreateChannel();    
List<Report> reports = client.GetByDescrip("this report");
```

Everything works if I don't have a breakpoint, but I want to step into the service functions.  How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug the service, you need to attach the process. To attach, CTRL + ALT + P or "Debug => Attach to Process...". Since you're using console application, you need to have both of your service and host running. While your host is running, attach the process, in this case, your process is "consoleHost.exe".